# Are all zeros of $\dfrac{\Gamma'}{\Gamma^2}(s) \pm \dfrac{\Gamma'}{\Gamma^2}(1-s)$ either real or on the line with $\Re(s)=\frac12$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, riemann-zeta-function, gamma-function

In [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/89324/are-all-zeros-of-gammas-pm-gamma1-s-on-a-line-with-real-part-frac12) it was proven that, except for a finite few, all zeros of $\Gamma(s) \pm \Gamma(1-s)$ are either real or reside on the line $\Re(s)=\frac12$.

I have been searching for similar reflexive $\pm$ $\Gamma$-functions that would not have a finite few exceptions and based on numerical evidence I like to conjecture that all zeros of:

$$\dfrac{\Gamma'}{\Gamma^2}(s) \pm \dfrac{\Gamma'}{\Gamma^2}(1-s)$$

or expressed differently with $\Psi(s)$ the [Digamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DigammaFunction.html):

$$\dfrac{\Psi}{\Gamma}(s) \pm \dfrac{\Psi}{\Gamma}(1-s)$$

are either real or reside on the line with $\Re(s)=\frac12$.

**Question:**

Could this be proven using the techniques applied to $\Gamma(s) \pm \Gamma(1-s)$ ?

*Just as a side observation:*

A similar effect appears to occur for [$\zeta(s) \pm \zeta(1-s)$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/89518/are-the-semi-trivial-zeros-of-zetas-pm-zeta1-s-all-on-the-critical-li) that (assuming the RH) also induces a finite few complex zeros lying off the critical line and these also seem to be absent when using:

$$\dfrac{\zeta'}{\zeta}(s) \pm \dfrac{\zeta'}{\zeta}(1-s)$$

as framed up in [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/206198/are-all-complex-zeros-of-dfrac-zeta-zetas-pm-dfrac-zeta-zeta1-s).

Comment: The bug is in my code. "derivative=1" doesn't compute the derivative as I wrongly thought. Will delete very soon.

Comment: X-Ray for the plus sign: https://s31.postimg.org/x81i3jp7v/agno2.png Doesn't show complex zeros off the line.

Comment: Using the gamma function's reflection formula, you can rewrite your expression as \begin{aligned}D\Big[-\frac{1}{\Gamma (s)}\pm\frac1{\Gamma(1-s)}\Big]&=D\Big[\frac{-\Gamma(1-s)\pm\Gamma(s)}{\pi\csc\pi s}\Big]\\
&=-\cos\pi s\;[\Gamma(1-s)\mp\Gamma(s)]+\pi^{-1}\sin\pi s\;[\Gamma'(1-s)\pm\Gamma'(s)]\end{aligned}so if [the answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/89324/are-all-zeros-of-gammas-pm-gamma1-s-on-a-line-with-real-part-frac12) you cited can be extended to $\sin\pi s\,(\Gamma'(1-s)\mp\Gamma'(s))$, (cont.)

Comment: then you can use it to confirm your conjecture.

In the case of the plus (top) sign, it follows easily that $s=1/2$ is a zero.